# kubernetes: How to view or list the installed CNI addons?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, cni

Suppose, I just installed one of the Kubernetes CNI plugins, for example `weave-net`:

```
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

How can I view or list the installed CNI plugins?

After installing how do I know that it is running?  Or if I `kubectl delete` the plugin, how do I know it was deleted?

After installing the plugin, I sort of expected to see some objects created for this plugin. So that if I want to delete it, then I don't have to remember the exact URL I used to install, I could just lookup the object name and delete it.

Answer (score 14):

if you list the pods in kube-system namespace, you can see the pods. The pod's names will be started with weave-net-xxxxx. Since it is Deamonset object, the pod's count will be based on your k8s nodes. Actually one pod will be created for one node.

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

Comment: In addition to this answer you can also check which one you have by running command `ls /etc/cni/net.d`. It will show your cni's conf.