# How can I detect CNI type/version in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubectl, microk8s, cni

Is there a Kubectl command or config map in the cluster that can help me find what CNI is being used?

Comment: Its a lil different but maybe this will help get you in the right direction:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814133/kubernetes-how-to-view-or-list-the-installed-cni-addons

Comment: Version of daemonset: `kubectl describe ds -n kube-flannel | grep -i image`

Answer (score 2):

First of all checking presence of exactly one config file in `/etc/cni/net.d` is a good start:

```
$ ls /etc/cni/net.d
10-flannel.conflist
```

and `ip a s` or `ifconfig` helpful for checking existence of network interfaces. e.g. `flannel` CNI should setup `flannel.1` interface:

```
$ ip a s flannel.1
3: flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/ether de:cb:d1:d6:e3:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.244.1.0/32 scope global flannel.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dccb:d1ff:fed6:e3e7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When creating a cluster, [CNI installation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) is typically installed using:

```
kubectl apply -f <add-on.yaml>
```

thus the networking pod will be called `kube-flannel*`, `kube-calico*` etc. depending on your [networking configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#how-to-implement-the-kubernetes-networking-model).

Then `crictl` will help you inspect running pods and containers.

```
crictl pods ls
```

On a controller node in a healthy cluster you should have all pods in `Ready` state.

```
crictl pods ls
POD ID              CREATED             STATE               NAME                                          NAMESPACE           ATTEMPT             RUNTIME
dc90dd87e18cf       3 minutes ago       Ready               coredns-6d4b75cb6d-r2j9s                      kube-system         0                   (default)
d1ab9d0aa815a       3 minutes ago       Ready               kubernetes-dashboard-cd4778d69-xmtkz          kube-system         0                   (default)
0c151fdd92e71       3 minutes ago       Ready               coredns-6d4b75cb6d-bn8hr                      kube-system         0                   (default)
40f18ce56f776       4 minutes ago       Ready               kube-flannel-ds-d4fd7                         kube-flannel        0                   (default)
0e390a68380a5       4 minutes ago       Ready               kube-proxy-r6cq2                              kube-system         0                   (default)
cd93e58d3bf70       4 minutes ago       Ready               kube-scheduler-c01            kube-system         0                   (default)
266a33aa5c241       4 minutes ago       Ready               kube-apiserver-c01            kube-system         0                   (default)
0910a7a73f5aa       4 minutes ago       Ready               kube-controller-manager-c01   kube-system         0                   (default)
```

If your cluster is properly configured you should be able to list containers using `kubectl`:

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

if `kubectl` is not working (`kube-apiserver` is not running) you can fallback to `crictl`.

On an unhealthy cluster `kubectl` will show pods in `CrashLoopBackOff` state. `crictl pods ls` command will give you similar picture, only displaying pods from single node. Also check [documentation for common CNI errors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/troubleshooting-cni-plugin-related-errors/).

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                          READY   STATUS              RESTARTS         AGE
coredns-6d4b75cb6d-brb9d                      0/1     ContainerCreating   0                25m
coredns-6d4b75cb6d-pcrcp                      0/1     ContainerCreating   0                25m
kube-apiserver-cm01            1/1     Running             27 (18m ago)     26m
kube-apiserver-cm02            0/1     Running             31 (8m11s ago)   23m
kube-apiserver-cm03            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    33 (2m22s ago)   26m
kube-controller-manager-cm01   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    13 (50s ago)     24m
kube-controller-manager-cm02   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    7 (15s ago)      24m
kube-controller-manager-cm03   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    15 (3m45s ago)   26m
kube-proxy-2dvfg                              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    8 (97s ago)      25m
kube-proxy-7gnnr                              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    8 (39s ago)      25m
kube-proxy-cqmvz                              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    8 (19s ago)      25m
kube-scheduler-cm01            1/1     Running             28 (7m15s ago)   12m
kube-scheduler-cm02            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    28 (4m45s ago)   18m
kube-scheduler-cm03            1/1     Running             36 (107s ago)    26m
kubernetes-dashboard-cd4778d69-g8jmf          0/1     ContainerCreating   0                2m27s
```

`crictl ps` will give you containers (like `docker ps`), watch for high number of attempts:

```
CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED             STATE               NAME                      ATTEMPT             POD ID              POD
d54c6f1e45dea       2ae1ba6417cbc       2 seconds ago       Running             kube-proxy                1                   347fef3ae1e98       kube-proxy-7gnnr
d6048ef9e30c7       d521dd763e2e3       41 seconds ago      Running             kube-apiserver            27                  640658b58d1ae       kube-apiserver-cm03
b6b8c7a24914e       3a5aa3a515f5d       41 seconds ago      Running             kube-scheduler            28                  c7b710a0acf30       kube-scheduler-cm03
b0a480d2c1baf       586c112956dfc       42 seconds ago      Running             kube-controller-manager   8                   69504853ab81b       kube-controller-manager-cm03
```

and check logs using

```
crictl logs d54c6f1e45dea
```

Last not least `/opt/cni/bin/` path usually contains binaries required for networking. Another `PATH` might defined in add on setup or CNI config.

```
$ ls /opt/cni/bin/
bandwidth  bridge  dhcp  firewall  flannel  host-device  host-local  ipvlan  loopback  macvlan  portmap  ptp  sbr  static  tuning  vlan
```

Finally `crictl` reads `/etc/crictl.yaml` config, you should set proper runtime and image endpoint to match you [container runtime](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/):

```
runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
image-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
timeout: 10
```

Comment: what would happen if we have two configs in the `/etc/cni/net.d` dir , I have a case where I am installing calico for just policy and keeping flannel on the side. Installing calico adds calico config as well in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Tombart's response:
If there are multiple CNI configuration files in the directory, the kubelet uses the configuration file that comes first by name in lexicographic order.